# WPF control ListView

Tags: wpf

In C# ListView -> ListItem -> subItem.

How to add a new entry to a list using WPF?

Comment: It would be nice if you write in full sentenses. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

To add data such as ListView WF, you must use binding.
For example:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="lv">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                         <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
                         <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Show data of two column(ID, Name) with this example

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hardly intelligible but let's just shoot into the blue:

Adding items in XAML:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>
        <!-- Item Content -->
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

In code behind:

```
listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = content });
```

(*ListViewItems do not have sub-items by the way*)